# How to require text in a Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I go about requiring text in a textbox? This is what i have so far.

```
String strName = txtName.Text;
String strEmail = txtEmail.Text;
Boolean blnErrors = false;

if (strName == null)
{

}
else
{
    string script = "alert(\"Name Field Is Required!\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);

    txtName.Focus();
}
```

When I run the program and try to execute it, I get the error popping up regardless if I have text entered into the textbox or not. I only want the Error to show if There is Nothing in the TextBox. I have also tried using,

```
if (strName == "")
```

as well. But nothing changes.

Comment: Your string is probably empty, not null. Try if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strName) ...

Comment: You're checking if the string is null and only showing an alert if it isn't.

Comment: There are out of the box validation tools you can use that are much nicer than this. Why re-invent the wheel? They do client-side validation too so saves a whole post-back for nothing!

Comment: @jac: Better yet, String.IsNullOrWhitespace(strName)

Comment: @Belogix and what about serve side ? you can not trust only client side. he'll has to do this check also.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yes, but that comes out of the box too. What I am saying is you get the benefit of client AND server side without having to do lots of work yourself.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Belogix is totally right, ASP validation is both server side and clientside out of the box. Most of the replies so far on this are miss guided and totally not the way it should be done. (And especially don't use alert(), no user will thank you for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this :

```
String strName = txtName.Text.Trim(); //add trim here
String strEmail = txtEmail.Text;
Boolean blnErrors = false;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sstrName)) //this function checks for both null or empty string.
{
    string script = "alert(\"Name Field Is Required!\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    txtName.Focus();
    return;//return from the function as there is an error.
}

//continue as usual .
```

Comment: Have you considered explaining the code? OP clearly lacks experience.

Comment: Removed, but please explain.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Dear it would be nice to suggest the OP to perform these validations at client side using `Javascript`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi client side validations should also be backup with server validations. I think he already knows from your comments that it should be first checked in client side. THEN in server side.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes you are right i was in a impression that if once client side side validation is done there is no need to perform same validation at serverside , but its true both client and serverside validations make the application more perfect:)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me using ScriptManager to do this kind of client validation is a bit overwhelming. A simple RequireFieldValidator will do what you are trying to do.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on my own. Here is the correct answer of what I wanted.

```
if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Name Field Is Required!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);

            txtName.Focus();
        }
```

This makes it so If the textbox is blank, it will show an error message. Otherwise, if there is text in the TextBox, nothing will happen. This is what I wanted.

Comment: I was using strings when i did not need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (txtName.TextLength==0)
{
//code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't do this, can you image the length of the IF statement if you had many textboxes on the page! See my answer, use validators

Answer (score 0):

As user3402321 said using a RequireFieldValidator is the correct approach for this.

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" >Please enter an email address</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

C#:

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    // Process submisison
}
```

If all the validators on the page pass validation Page.IsValid will be true, if one validator fails, IsValid will be false. Also for an email address you might want to use a RegEx validator to check the email format is correct:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="<your favourite email regex pattern>" Text="Email not correct format" />
```

Obviously change `<your favourite email regex pattern>` to an email regex pattern of your chosing.

**EDIT**
Further to what I've already said you can user a `<asp:ValidationSummary />` control to show all of the validation errors in one place and if you set the ShowMessageBox property to true it will display the message in a javascript `alert()` message box.